# JS (ajax) array - output and style with HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me to understand me how to use array - passed to ajax - to output and style database information in html?

**PHP sample:**

For example: I have an array called $query.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

   echo '<div>'.$row["name"].'</div>';
   echo '<div>'.$row["surname"].'</div>';
   echo '<div>'.$row["address"].'</div>';

}
```

**JQuery:**

What if i pass that same $query array to ajax (javascript)? How can i output it in similar way that i did with php? For example: to print each name, surname and address inside separate divs.

```
...success: function(data) { ? }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: does your data come back just as a comma seperated string ?

Comment: Not for now, but if it is easier i can serialize it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rows = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

__

```
...success: function(data) {
    var result = "";
    $.each(data, function(i,e) {
        result += '<div>'+e+'</div>'; //or e.name etc. depending on the structure?
    });
    $("#elementID").append(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

John, you're confusing how PHP and javascript work. PHP is a server-side scripting language, whereas javascript is client-side.

They WILL NEVER see each other's data. The only way to pass data from PHP to javascript is to print it as a string or send it as JSON-encoded data (still printed to the page).

If you want your onSuccess to see the `$query` array you'll have to output JSON-encoded data by calling `json_encode($query)`

```
<?php
// backgroundScript.php
echo json_encode($query);
```

Then you can parse it in javascript as JSON data.

[Here's a pretty good tutorial on JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)